# how can I use lets encrypt when routing through CloudFlare?

Tags: security, ssl, cloudflare, lets-encrypt

Lets Encrypt only works then the domain name used is pointing to the server. When you use CloudFlare (or similar), the domain name does not point to the final destination server.

What is the best way to deal with this? How can you ensure security between CF and the final hosting destination?

Comment: With CF the origin server doesn't really need a widely-trusted cert like LE; you only need one trusted _by CF_; see https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/ .  (_Clients_ see the cert generated by CF itself, which is widely-trusted.)